# pandas drop row based on index vs ix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop pandas dataframe row based on its index (not location).

The data frame looks like

```
                      DO  
129518  a developer and   
20066   responsible for   
571     responsible for   
85629   responsible for   
5956    by helping them
```

(FYI: "DO" is a column name)

I want to delete the row where its index is 571 so I did:

```
df=df.drop(df.index[571])
```

then I check
    df.ix[571]

then what the hell it's still there!

So I thought "ok, maybe index and ix are different!"

```
In [539]: df.index[571]
17002
```

My question is

1) What is index? (compared to ix)

2) How do I delete the index row 571 using ix?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the desired value from the index directly:

```
df.drop(571, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df.index
```

Is the index of the dataframe.

```
df.index[571]
```

Is the 571st element of the index. Then you dropped whatever that was. You didn't want positional but that's what you did.

Use @John Zwinck's answer