# Moving Data in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have the following df:

```
               Mid         South         North
              Elec          Elec          Elec
t
0                0             0             0
1     43102.490062  43102.490062  43102.490062
2     41692.002871  41692.002871  41692.002871
3     40592.822117  40592.822117  40592.822117
...
```

**I want to convert it to following df**:

```
               Mid         South         North
              Elec          Elec          Elec
t
0     43102.490062  43102.490062  43102.490062
1     41692.002871  41692.002871  41692.002871
2     40592.822117  40592.822117  40592.822117
...
```

So basically I need to move the data 1 row above.

*Eg. If I have indexes (0-3), I should have indexes (0-2)*

Comment: did you look at `pandas.Dataframe.shift`?

Comment: This question addresses your issue I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802076/pandas-drop-row-based-on-index-vs-ix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to shift an index:

```
import pandas as pd
# Recreate your example dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'t': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'Mid Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8], 'South Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8], 'North Elec': [0., 43102.5, 41692.0, 40592.8]})
df.set_index('t', inplace=True)
df = df.shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   Mid Elec  South Elec  North Elec
t                                  
0   43102.5     43102.5     43102.5
1   41692.0     41692.0     41692.0
2   40592.8     40592.8     40592.8
3       NaN         NaN         NaN
```

To drop the final row, just use standard Python list indexing:

```
df = df[:-1]
```

Output:

```
   Mid Elec  South Elec  North Elec
t                                  
0   43102.5     43102.5     43102.5
1   41692.0     41692.0     41692.0
2   40592.8     40592.8     40592.8
```

Comment: works but 1 question, I also want to remove the last index because now last index values are NaN, can I do it in 1 commend or should I use drop?